# How to catch errors in handlers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

The handler in my code fails in some cases which then causes the whole playbook run to crash and I would like to catch those failures in the handler and do some sort of clean up.

Here's my playbook where I would ideally like the `Rescue when handler fails` task to run:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: something something
      block:
        - name: Print a message
          debug: msg='I execute normally'
          changed_when: yes
          notify: failing handler
      rescue:
        - name: Rescue when handler fails
          debug:
            msg: 'Rescue'
  handlers:
    - name: failing handler
      command: /bin/false
```

How can I catch the failure from this `failing handler` and run some tasks for cleanup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, the above can't work as the time when your handler is notified and the time it will effectively run are totally distinct. You need to catch the failure when the handler runs, not when it is notified.

I would go that way.

Put your handler tasks in a file `my_failing_handler.yaml`

```yaml
- block:
    - name: the task that might fail
      command: /bin/false
  rescue:
    - name: rescue when handler fails
      debug:
        msg: "rescue"
```

Then in your main playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      debug: msg='I execute normally'
      changed_when: yes
      notify: failing handler

  handlers:
    - name: failing handler
      include_tasks: my_failing_handler.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks, this combination works. In the actual codebase, my handler is actually already defined in it's own file in the handlers directory of my role(`roles/somerole/handlers/main.yml`). It seems like to add a rescue block to it, I would have to add another file(`my_failing_handler.yaml`) for include_tasks, which would make it more complicated. Is there any other way you can think of without adding another file to keep simpler?

Comment: That's the only way I know to have several tasks for one handler.

Comment: Is it just me or does this not work (anymore)? I copied the playbook and handler exactly as stated in the answer, but when I run it with ansible [core 2.14.2] on my system, the handler fails but the rescue doesn't trigger, resulting in "localhost : ok=3 changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0   ignored=0".

Answer (score 2):

By default handlers run at the end of the section (`pre_tasks`, `tasks`, etc.) from where they are notified. However it is possible to trigger the handler immediately after a task by using a [meta action](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html), i.e. `- meta: flush_handlers`.

Using this technique, we can trigger the handler immediately after the `Print a message` task. Then the playbook can continue with the next task(s).

For example:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      debug:
        msg: i execute normally
      changed_when: true
      notify: failing handler

    - meta: flush_handlers

    - name: rescue when handler fails
      debug:
        msg: rescue
      when: _handler_status | default({}) is failed

  handlers:
    - name:  failing handler
      command: /bin/false
      register: _handler_status
      ignore_errors: true
```

As rightly pointed out by @Zeitounator, flushing handlers is fine for the above example where there is only 1 notifying task. However it may be undesirable when there are chances of other tasks notifying other handlers. In such case, the task can go under `post_tasks` section. Like below:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      debug:
        msg: i execute normally
      changed_when: true
      notify: failing handler

  post_tasks:
    - name: rescue when failing handler fails
      debug:
        msg: rescue
      when: _handler_status | default({}) is failed

  handlers:
    - name:  failing handler
      command: /bin/false
      register: _handler_status
      ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: Note that this will trigger **all** handlers that have been notified to date (and not only the immediately preceding one). An other option would be to not flush and add the rescue task in the `post_tasks` section of the playbook.

Comment: Agreed! It makes more sense to have the handler rescue task in `post_tasks` rather than flushing handlers in actual scenario where multiple handlers could have been notified.

Comment: Note that this can't work for handlers you notify in `post_tasks` as they will run after the `post_tasks` are done. This is basically why I lke the include much better since everything is taking place just as the handler is run no matter when it was notified and triggered.